# How to explain to g++ compiler to read a list of 'include' dirs used to search for .h files from a 'list' file

Tags: c++, g++

Perhaps it would be better to elaborate the question.

So I have a compiling line like:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cxx
```

Then because main.css insists on loading 'header.h' which shall be sought in 'search_dir' which is not part of STL so i need to 'include' search dir in compiling options like:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cxx -I/path/to/search_dir
```

then say I have 30 search dirs (search_dir1 .. search_dir30)...

So, I would include them as:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cxx -I/path/to/search_dir1 -I/path/to/search_dir2 .....  -I/path/to/search_dir30
```

the command line gets insanely long and unreadable. SO is there are an option to save all:

```
/path/to/search_dir1
/path/to/search_dir2
...
/path/to/search_dir30
```

into a file called for example 'my_search_dirs' and then tell g++ something like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cxx -If=my_search_dirs
```

of course I 'invented' option -If (someting like: 'include file with a list of search dirs').

I have read manuals and researched on the net and stack overflow and could not find anything remotely asking or discussing this (or answering)

is there an option for this in g++ ?

Comment: Why don't you use a Makefile, including your search directories? The same problem you're mentioning will arise when compiling multiple files that main.cxx depends on.

Comment: Because of Makefile I am asking this. Because Makefile line gets insane...

Comment: Break the line to multiple lines with backslash at the end of each.

Comment: Break the line to multiple lines ..... this is what I currently do,  but it looks very inelegant :(
Perhaps Makefile shall not look elegant. Perhaps it just needs to work.

Comment: Other than the idea with one include file, at some point you'll have to write down every directory. In my opinion the approach using bash is even more 'inelegant' as you have to write down everything aswell (unless you really use dir1, dir2 etc.), which would be even more inelegant (you see where this is going?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this.

Create a file with any name, say, `cc_opts` containing all the many `-Idir` options you
need, just as you would write them on the commandline, or, if you prefer, broken
over multiple lines. E.g.

**cc_opts**

```
-I/path/to/search_dir1 -I/path/to/search_dir2 -I/path/to/search_dir3
```

Save it to your build directory. Then, in your compiler commandline, replace:

```
-I/path/to/search_dir1 -I/path/to/search_dir2 -I/path/to/search_dir3
```

with:

```
@cc_opts
```

Then gcc/g++ will read options from `cc_opts` and interpolate them in
the commandline in place of `@cc_opts`.

You may include any options you like in the `@`-file, not just `-I`-options.

See the [`@file` option in the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)

Before exploiting this convenience, bear in mind that when it falls to you to
debug the failure of an automated build guided by its build log, it may be more
helpful to you to see:

```
g++ ... -I/path/to/search_dir1 -I/path/to/search_dir2 -I/path/to/search_dir3 ...
```

than:

```
g++ ... @path/to/optionsfile ...
```

And also that a buildsystem consisting of:

**Makefile**

```
...
CPPFLAGS := -I/path/to/search_dir1 \
            -I/path/to/search_dir2 \
            -I/path/to/search_dir3
...
```

is clearer and more robust than one consisting of:

**Makefile**

```
    ...
    CPPFLAGS := @inc_opts
    ...
```

and:

**inc_opts**

```
-I/path/to/search_dir1 -I/path/to/search_dir2 -I/path/to/search_dir3
```

These considerations explain which GCC `@`-files are rarely seen.

Comment: This is a very interesting option. Thank you! Did not try it as yet, but this is what I was looking for. The problem is experimenting not creating targets, perhaps once experimented with different libraries I could make minimal (and therefore what you call 'robust' or perhaps 'user-friendly' way of doing it). Usually, this is final touch before making something deployable, but until then I need an easy way to experiment with search lists. This also proves that gcc has an option, I just could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cxx `while read line; do printf "%c-I$line "; done < file.txt`
```

with **file.txt** containing all your dirs.

Comment: I suspected that bash script will come to the rescue at the end. Hoped not to need to go that direction. But hey! This world is pragmatic, why bother to have function when it can be 'fixed' outside.
At any rate thank you for the idea and approach.